# Getting consistent, immediate backend shutdown on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, backend

Whenever I try to start a task on my GAE backend, its gets shutdown almost immediately.  I've looked at the documentation regarding the reasons for shutdown but I can't determine the cause.  The is no evidence of excess CPU or memory.  It happens every time.

I added the shutdown handler and it is getting invoked.  Before I put in the handler, I got no log entries from my code, only the "Process terminated because the backend took too long to shutdown" message.  Now with the handler I get the initial log entry and the exception that results from the interruptAllRequests call in the handler.

Any ideas?

Log image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7DAd.jpg

2014-04-04 11:35:27.372 /camperschoicecloud/task 500 6357ms 0kb instance=0 AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine) module=default version=sched-backend
D 2014-04-04 11:35:24.883 com.stellarcoresoftware.camperschoice.server.NamespaceFilter doFilter: Server Name: sched-backend.campers-choice.appspot.com
I 2014-04-04 11:35:24.891 com.stellarcoresoftware.camperschoice.server.TaskServiceImpl doPost: executing task: sched, entity 6288495693791232
E 2014-04-04 11:35:27.366 com.stellarcoresoftware.camperschoice.server.util.JobUtil getJob: Error reading job com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CancelledException: The API cal

2014-04-04 11:35:25.878 /_ah/stop 200 100ms 0kb instance=0 module=default version=sched-backend
[04/Apr/2014:08:35:25 -0700] "GET /_ah/stop HTTP/1.1" 200 2 - - "0.sched-backend.campers-choice.appspot.com" ms=101 cpu_ms=8 cpm_usd=0.000000 instance=0 app_engine_release=1.9.2 
E 2014-04-04 11:35:25.868
com.stellarcoresoftware.camperschoice.server.TaskServiceImpl$1 shutdown: Shutdown Hook

2014-04-04 11:35:24.876 /_ah/start 404 3809ms 0kb instance=0 module=default version=sched-backend
[04/Apr/2014:08:35:24 -0700] "GET /_ah/start HTTP/1.1" 404 234 - - "0.sched-backend.campers-choice.appspot.com" ms=3810 cpu_ms=2232 cpm_usd=0.000026 loading_request=1 instance=0 app_engine_release=1.9.2 
D 2014-04-04 11:35:24.834
com.stellarcoresoftware.camperschoice.server.NamespaceFilter doFilter: Server Name: 0.sched-backend.campers-choice.appspot.com
I 2014-04-04 11:35:24.873
This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.

Comment: What causes the DataException? Try fixing this error first.

Comment: As I mentioned, the exception is caused by the interruptAllRequests() call.

Answer (score 0):

I'm solved the issue by changing the backend class from B1 to B4.  That leads me to believe it was a memory problem even though I there are no specific indications of that.  I see that on the Python side there are easy methods to check CPU and memory.  Are there Java equivalents?